# Spring MVC content negotiation fails while serving a BufferedImage

Tags: java, spring-mvc, content-type, content-negotiation

I'm trying to serve an image in my application as a java.awt.BufferedImage object. When I attempt to perform a GET, here are the results:

- Accept:image/jpeg renders a valid picture
- Accept:*/* returns an HTTP 406

Here is the relevant part of my servlet-context.xml:

```
    <beans:bean id="messageAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="order" value="1" />
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:array>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </beans:array>
    </beans:property>

</beans:bean>
```

And here is my Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "photo/{photoId:[0-9]+}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public BufferedImage getPhoto(
        @PathVariable long photoId) {
        return photoService.getPhoto(photoId);
    }
```

MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE is "image/jpeg". It is my understanding that an accept header of */* would never generate a HTTP 406, which according to [this page](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html) tells us that the caller doesn't accept content of that type.

This is an issue because most browsers have "*/*" in their accept headers, and would not be able to view this image unless the user hard-coded the accept header.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Message converters are picky about the Accept header, and they have to be since they are applied to all handlers annotated with `@ResponseBody`.

A couple of ways you can get around this:

Option 1: Extend the BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter to handle `*/*` as well, NOTE: this can have unintended consequences if you add other message-converters later on as all of a sudden, handlers you want to produce JSON starts producing images instead.

```
public class ExtendedBufferedImageHttpMessageConverter extends BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter {

    @Override
    public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
    if (mediaType.equals(MediaType.ALL)) {
        return super.canWrite(clazz, MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
    } else {
        return super.canWrite(clazz, mediaType);
    }
}
```

Then use this instead of the normal BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter in your spring config.

Option 2: Create a filter or interceptor that is applied to your image requests and wrap the request in such a way the `Accept` header looks like `image/jpeg` instead of `*/*`. This will "trick" spring into thinking that the client accepts jpeg and trigger the BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter.

Comment: Hmmmm interesting. This definitely sheds light on the issue, but my app needs to serve up application/json data as well. I didn't include it in my example, but I use the MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter as well. When that was added back in of course the servlet tried to serialize the image and return JSON. I guess what I'm trying to do is use the BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter the way it was intended, I think.

Comment: Also wanted to add that to work around this (or maybe this is the solution) I put the raw data in a byte array in the @ResponseBody and included a ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter that supports image/jpeg. I can include the source for this if anyone is interested.